# Python "except Error as err:"

Tags: python, exception

i just started learning python yesterday and I'm trying to build a program that can navigate my Linux file system. I found this code online which works fine, but I don't understand the exception handling. The format of a try block is

```
errors = [] 

try
    ...

except OSError as why:
    errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
except Error as err:
    errors.extend(err.args[0])
```

I can't find any description of an 'Error' type of exception. I can however find a description of 'OSError' in the python docs. Is 'Error' used to refer to any type of exception?

Comment: `Error` might be a custom exception defined elsewhere in the script.

Comment: check the imports lines if you have anything like `from ... import Error`

Answer (score 4):

`Error` is likely to have been defined as a custom class for exceptions. In fact, it's tradition to define `Error` as the `base class` for all custom exceptions.

For more information, see [this `python` doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions):